# Check if user has configured a screen lock method (PIN/biometric/pattern/etc) using Flutter?

Tags: flutter, fingerprint, lockscreen, face-id, screen-lock

I want to check if the user has any type of screen lock set on their device (PIN, fingerprint, face, pattern, etc.).

I don't want to simply check if the device is *capable* of for example biometrics, nor detect (from the background) if the device is currently locked. I want to know if the user has **configured** any kind of lock mechanism at all for their device.

All the resources and code snippets I've come across so far seem to focus on

- checking if the device has biometric capabilities, **or**
- actually requesting authentication using biometric/PIN/pattern, **or**
- checking if the device is currently locked (when the app is in the background)

I want to simply check if the device has any type of locking configured and required to unlock the phone. If it doesn't, I want to hide some sensitive information in my app.

Is there any way to do this on both Android and iOS?

Answer (score -1):

To check whether there is local authentication available on this device or not, call canCheckBiometrics (if you need biometrics support) and/or isDeviceSupported() (if you just need some device-level authentication)

https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth

Comment: `isDeviceSupported()` checks for hardware support. `canCheckBiometrics` checks if fingerprint/iris..etc are enrolled. and `getAvailableBiometrics()` sometimes returns empty [ ] when only pattern is present. so the options are very limited with local_auth

Comment: those methods from `local_auth` don't work if the device only has PIN